# Android MediaPlayer can not play the audio file online but work well if load the same one from local

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Some thing weird happened when I use android MediaPlayer to play some audio stream from service.Here is my audio stream url:
http://7xk2r8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/rNeDSn1Octc
When I use it with MediaPlayer like this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://7xk2r8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/rNeDSn1Octc")
```

The onCompleteListener will be called immediately

But if I download the file from above url to android device,and use MediaPlayer to load it from local like this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("local path")
```

Everything works fine!

I think the bugs may from the stream file itself,but I don't know why,I have been lost in it for about 2 weeks,Help!!!!!!

PS:I used the most simple code for MediaPlayer,So I think it's fine with my code,I am sure that the bugs from audio stream file itself,could you test the file?The file URL above is totally public.Thanks!

Comment: onCompleteListener will be called immediately after mediaPlayer start

Comment: The android version is 22

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. Mediaplayer sometimes can not load cause of network proxy etc. You could call prepareAsync() but it will never invoke to onPrepared(). So I add a boolean flag like follow:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    isPrepared = true;}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(isPrepared) {// Do your code}
```